# lsusb detects the device but it still doesn't mount

Tags: 12.04, command-line, usb, mount, hard-drive

I have a WD passport external hard drive which used to work fine as recently as this morning. Now when I connect it with my laptop, nothing happens. Here's what I done so far:

`lsusb` detects the drive

```
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 1058:0810 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
```

But `lsblk` doesn't list it:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    40M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   360G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0     2M  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda8   8:8    0    97G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Here's the ouput of `dmesg | grep Western` when I connect my drive:

```
[ 2958.457685] usb 4-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[ 2958.474106] usb 4-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=0810
[ 2958.474114] usb 4-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2958.474118] usb 4-3: Product: My Passport 0810
[ 2958.474121] usb 4-3: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 2958.474124] usb 4-3: SerialNumber: 575841314132343233313239
[ 2958.535871] usb-storage 4-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2958.536036] scsi7 : usb-storage 4-3:1.0
[ 2958.536364] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 2959.536600] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       My Passport 0810 1049 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2959.536809] scsi 7:0:0:1: Enclosure         WD       SES Device       1049 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 2959.537329] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 2959.537639] scsi 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 13
[ 2959.539120] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[ 2965.835715] scsi 7:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x8000002
[ 2965.835731] scsi 7:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[ 2965.835751] ses 7:0:0:1: Attached Enclosure device
[ 2960.543901] .....ready
[ 3150.068843] sd 7:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 3330.282651] sd 7:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 3379.475671] type=1400 audit(1450611724.692:67): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1221 comm="cupsd" pid=1221 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
[ 3510.492619] sd 7:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 3510.492694] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
[ 3510.492700] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 3510.492702] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 3510.492704] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 3510.492707] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 3510.492711] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 3510.492715] ASC=0x30 <<vendor>> ASCQ=0x8d
[ 3690.706412] sd 7:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 3690.706490] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 3814.511386] usb 4-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 3814.519385] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[ 3814.519390] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 3814.519846] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] READ CAPACITY failed
[ 3814.519851] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[ 3814.519853] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

What could be wrong with it? Also, let me know if I need to add any more information.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the logs show, the Linux kernel thinks, that either your USB drive or the USB host controller is faulty/broken. If it works on other USB ports on the same machine, it's the host controller. If it works on other operating systems or kernel versions, you should consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Other USB devices on the same USB port work properly. So it means that there is some problem with external hard drive.  Any idea
 what the problem could be?

Comment: Nope, not really. Speaking from personal experience with hard drives and external drive cases, sometimes the controller becomes wonky over time. This can be due to firmware bugs or wear on the electronic parts, neither of which you can fix without a deep understanding of them, and even if you do, it's usually not worth it considering the prices of new hardware.

Comment: I agree with @DavidFoerster, my laptop sometimes detects devices and sometimes not. It doesn't directly correlate with device or usb port. The best way to make it working is to plug the device prior to booting.